# What is the best kind of diagram to illustrate the workings of a semaphores / multiprocess / shared memory program?

Tags: multithreading, diagram, semaphore, shared-memory, diagrams

I have made a small project in which I have used various processes / shared memory / semaphores.

I am now going to have to explain my code and the program logic to both my lecturer and a couple of colleagues.

I am thus wondering what kind of notation/diagrams do people usually use for depicting this kind of programs. Activity diagrams? Flowchart Diagrams? What else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my course threading issues are explained to us by using something like graphs, mark the critical points (more precisely the points where syncronization is need) and explained how do you solve the problem. It works really well this way if you mark the critical points for example:

```
          T1           T2            T3
        method A      method A       method A
               \         /             /
                \       /             /
                 critical    section 1
                  /
                 /
              method B
```

and so on